# MongoDB structure and JSON, are they not the same?

Tags: json, mongodb

Let's say I have a json object:

```
Object = {
param1: '',
param2: '',
param3: '',
param4: {
    paramA: '',
    paramB: '',
    paramC: '',
    paramD: [AnotherJsonObject1,AnotherJsonObject2]
    }
}
```

Will my MongoDB structure not be similar? Would this type of structuring make the data (or some of it) less searchable?

**Edit 1:**

1. By less searchable I mean: if the top level entities have sub entities which themselves have sub-entities and so on. Will I be able to reach the lowest level entities with the same efficiency of those in the top level?
2. I currently depend heavily on JSON files in my website. Those files need not be indexed to searchable, BUT they would fit in the DB logically.

For example: I have a director, the director has the list of movies he created, every movie in this list has itself a list of actors who play in it, and every actor has a bio.

The bio in this example doesn't need to be indexed. I can just include a link to the file that contains the actor's bio, but I am wondering whether I can just add this to the DB because this way it will all fit in logically, or will 'unnecessary' data will harm the db's ability to perform efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongodb stores the document in a BSON format. It will appear similar to JSON structure.

The structure you explained seems to be a proper use case of nested documents.
You can query nested fields using the `.` operator

> Would this type of structuring make the data (or some of it) less
>   searchable?

It depends on your nested data structure and the kind of queries on those fields. There may be some limitations or queries may be a bit more complicated in nested structure cases in case on nested docs. However, as far the searchability of your nested docs is concerned, it entirely depends on your use case.

For eg.

```
director:[movies:[{movieName:"movie1", actors:[{firstName:"will", lastName:"smith"}, {firstName:"bruce", lastName:"willis"}]}]]
```

In the above scenario, if you have search for a director where any of the directed movies has actor with firstName as will and lastName as smith may turn out to be a bit more complex.

a simple query like 
`{director.movies.actors.firstName:"will", director.movies.actors.lastName:"smith"}`

may return a false response

The doc : `director:[movies:[actors:actors:[{firstName:"will", lastName:"willis"}, {firstName:"bruce", lastName:"smith"}]]]`

will also turn out to be a positive match.

Also, negation queries like where `firstName!="bruce"` will also return both the documents.

You may like to go through the mongodb docs for the same

For the first case, you can refer to [elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

Comment: so if I want to 
find({param4.paramC: 3}) for example, will it take longer then looking for find({param2: 3})

Comment: you can create an index on "param4.paramC" to make your queries optimized for searches on this field

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is proving very helpful! would you mind taking a look at question 2 in my edit?

Comment: I edited the answer. Let me know if it answers your query